# .Click() function not working Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a module which contains two pages one being the **product.php** and the other being the **filterproducts.php**

**Product.php** contains a Div Element which gets loaded by the **.load()** present inside the **product.php**

```
<div id="limitpage">
</div>
```

The **.load()** function makes an ajax call and get the output from the **filterproducts.php**

Structure of **product.php** looks like this

```
 <button id="nex" >clickme</button>
     <div id="limitpage">
        </div>
    <script>
          //Both of them are in document ready function
          $('#nexus').on('click',function () {

                alert("here");

            });
        $('#nex').click(function(){
           $('#limitpage').load("filterproducts.php");
        })

    </script>
```

**filterproducts.php** contains  a button

```
<button id="nexus">Next Page</button>
```

But ,when the page gets loaded *on('click',function())* doesn't work.Why is this exactly happening?
What is the workaround to do the same,if this one is not possible.

Comment: You need event delegation. Something like `$('#limitpage').on('click', '#nexus', function () {...});`

Comment: If you're loading `filterproducts.php` *asynchronously*, the binding wont find a `nexus` element because it hans't been added to the DOM yet.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I mean i am new to jquery php.

Comment: @AdamKonieska so how can i add it to DOM?

Comment: Go here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and read about "Delegated Events" as @putvande suggests.

Comment: You don't need ready if the script tag is at the end of the body, did you try debugging it using console.log(' ... '), try switching to on('click',...

Comment: .load() has an optional completion handler - you could bind your on click handler in there, since nexus would exist by then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the document is ready, the output from `filterproducs.php` is not yet present in the page, so `$('#nexus')` will return an empty set, and so it is *not* bound.

The solution is to bind something that is present in the page, and filter at the moment of the click. A typical example:

```
$(document).on('click', '#nexus', function() { 
  alert('nexus clicked!'); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an event delegation. Just consider this as a replacement of `.live() // deprecated now`. This will bind the click function to your button

```
$(document).on('click', '#nexus', function() { 
  alert('nexus clicked!'); 
})
```